# How to load model.safetensors using fast_bert using python

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have trained a model using latest `transformers` package `4.37.2` and it saves the model as `model.safetensors`.

I am using `from fast_bert.prediction import BertClassificationPredictor` to load the model. But it's giving the error as

```
OSError: Error no file named ['pytorch_model.bin', 'tf_model.h5', 'model.ckpt.index'] found in directory  or `from_tf` set to False
```

Does `BertClassificationPredictor` allow us to load `model.safetensors`. If yes, how can we do this?

```
predictor = BertClassificationPredictor(model_path=self.model_path,
                                                     label_path=self.label_path,
                                                     multi_label=False,
                                                     model_type='roberta',
                                                     do_lower_case=True)
```